# Alternativ for HtmlUtilities.decodeColor

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, itextpdf

I passed my pdf-generator project from lowagie-4.2.0_17 to itextpdf-5.5.6

In my project I have

```
Color.decode(colorString)
```

I replace it by

```
HtmlUtilities.decodeColor(colorString)
```

but it is Deprecated

What alternativ exists for `HtmlUtilities.decodeColor()` ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding.

It is not our intention to deprecate `HtmlUtilities.decodeColor()`. That method is used throughout iText and XML Worker. However, `HtmlUtilities.decodeColor()` still uses the deprecated `WebColors` class:

```
public static BaseColor decodeColor(String s) {
    if (s == null)
        return null;
    s = s.toLowerCase().trim();
    try {
        return WebColors.getRGBColor(s);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The class `WebColors` is deprecated. At some point in time, the content of the method `WebColors.getRGBColor()` will be moved into `HtmlUtilities` and the class `WebColors` will disappear.

I'm not sure how you detected that `HtmlUtilities.decodeColor()` is deprecated. It *uses* a deprecated class (for now), but the method itself isn't deprecated.

Comment: Now I see, that it is a misunderstanding. Thank you

Comment: The itextpdf docs for HtmlUtilities show it deprecated from 5.5.2.